# how do i broadcast Bluetooth inquiry with python sockets AF_bluetooth socket?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, bluetooth

Well at the moment I try to learn more about Bluetooth, I've realized that to connect I need to send a packet to the device called inquiry packet. However for my script I'm more interested in broadcasting it, and even though pybluez provides the high level functions for it. I want to do it with sockets as part of learning experience. Can anyone please tell me, how to specify I want to send the inquiry packet? through the sockets like so
`s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)`
and how do I broadcast it, instead of sending to one adress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking to create a Serial Port Profile (SPP) socket server?

Any example of that is below.

I have used the [pydbus](https://pypi.org/project/pydbus/) library to get the Bluetooth adapter address but you could just hardcode the mac address if you preferred:

```py
import socket
import pydbus

bus = pydbus.SystemBus()
adapter = bus.get('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')

adapter_addr = adapter.Address
port = 3  # Normal port for rfcomm?
buf_size = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.bind((adapter_addr, port))
s.listen(1)
try:
    print('Listening for connection...')
    client, address = s.accept()
    print(f'Connected to {address}')

    while True:
        data = client.recv(buf_size)
        if data:
            print(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Something went wrong: {e}')
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

Comment: you can use socket.BDADDR_ANY instead of adapter_addr: `s.bind((socket.BDADDR_ANY, port))`